# Type mismatch: NavController (NavHost)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navhostfragment

I'm kinda new to jetpack compose kotlin.
Type mismatch: inferred type is NavController but NavHostController was expected
The piece of code in MainActivity that raises the error
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = APPS_ROUTE) {

```
fun BodyContent(paddingValues: PaddingValues, navController: NavController) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = APPS_ROUTE) {
            composable(APPS_ROUTE) { AppsScreen() }
            composable(WIDGETS_ROUTE) { WidgetsScreen() }
            composable(SETTINGS_ROUTE) { SettingsScreen() }
        }
    }
}
```

Type mismatch
Required:NavHostController
Found: NavController
value-parameter navController: NavController

This is my code in MainActivity.kt

```
package hr.filipal.iconflex

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.BottomNavigation
import androidx.compose.material.BottomNavigationItem
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Home
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Settings
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Widgets
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import hr.filipal.iconflex.AppDestinations.APPS_ROUTE
import hr.filipal.iconflex.AppDestinations.SETTINGS_ROUTE
import hr.filipal.iconflex.AppDestinations.WIDGETS_ROUTE
import hr.filipal.iconflex.screens.AppsScreen
import hr.filipal.iconflex.screens.SettingsScreen
import hr.filipal.iconflex.screens.WidgetsScreen
import hr.filipal.iconflex.ui.theme.IconFlexTheme


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            IconFlexTheme {
                MainScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { SearchBar() },
        bottomBar = { BottomNavigationBar(navController) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        BodyContent(innerPadding, navController)
    }
}

@Composable
fun SearchBar() {
    // Implementacija trake za pretragu
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            TextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange = { /* Ovdje ažurirate state s novom vrijednošću */ },
                placeholder = { Text("Search apps") },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            )
        },
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface
    )
}

@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController) {
    val currentRoute = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination?.route
    BottomNavigation {
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Home, contentDescription = null) },
            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.navigation_apps)) },
            selected = currentRoute == APPS_ROUTE,
            onClick = {
                if (currentRoute != APPS_ROUTE) {
                    navController.navigate(APPS_ROUTE)
                }
            }
        )
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Widgets, contentDescription = null) },
            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.navigation_widgets)) },
            selected = currentRoute == WIDGETS_ROUTE,
            onClick = {
                if (currentRoute != WIDGETS_ROUTE) {
                    navController.navigate(WIDGETS_ROUTE)
                }
            }
        )
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Settings, contentDescription = null) },
            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.navigation_settings)) },
            selected = currentRoute == SETTINGS_ROUTE,
            onClick = {
                if (currentRoute != SETTINGS_ROUTE) {
                    navController.navigate(SETTINGS_ROUTE)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun BodyContent(paddingValues: PaddingValues, navController: NavController) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = APPS_ROUTE) {
            composable(APPS_ROUTE) { AppsScreen() }
            composable(WIDGETS_ROUTE) { WidgetsScreen() }
            composable(SETTINGS_ROUTE) { SettingsScreen() }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    IconFlexTheme {
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

This is my builg.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "hr.filipal.iconflex"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "hr.filipal.iconflex"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"


        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
        targetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.4"
    }

    packaging {
        resources.excludes.add("/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}")
    }

    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
}
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.20")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.4")
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.5.4")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

I tried to add import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostController and other parts of the package but it didn't help